# how can I decode webm file to raw pcm?

Tags: c++, voice, webm, opus

overall procedure is like below.
client record the voice for some duration(ex, 5 sec) in some format(webm or wav)
then it send it to server using websocket.

server received the several packets(each packet size is 4096bytes), and each packet is sent to opus decoder.
but opus decoder return invalid packet error.

server is coded with c++(using libwebsocket and libopus library) in ubuntu.

could anyone help me how to do ?
general procedure or some example code is ok
its difficult to find info or community.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The opus decoder may be expecting an Ogg Opus container file.  If you're using WebM, you could extract the encoded audio pages and pass them to a raw Opus decoder that is not dependent on the Ogg container.  You could also see how the [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) project is decoding WebM Opus files to PCM

Could the client send an Ogg Opus file instead of a WebM Opus file?  There's a chunk-based decoder written in C that can decode Ogg Opus files very quickly.  It's intended for WebAssembly, but the C code is not dependent on WASM.  See `opus_chunk_decoder.c`:

https://github.com/AnthumChris/opus-stream-decoder/tree/master/src